# Is the axiom of choice necessary for "a set is open iff it is a neighborhood of all its points"?

Tags: general-topology, axiom-of-choice

Note: by neighborhood of $x$ we mean a set $N$ s.t. there exists open $U$ s.t. $x \in U \subseteq N$.

We only care about the "if" as the "only if" is trivial. The usual proof goes as follows. Suppose $U$ if a neighborhood of all its points, i.e. $\forall x\in U \exists V_x$ open s.t. $x \in V_x \subseteq U$. Then $\bigcup_{x \in U} V_x = U$ (as is easy to check) and hence $U$ is open as the union of open sets. The point that I think we need choice is in taking the union $\bigcup_{x \in U} V_x$ as we are effectively doing an arbitrary amount of existential instantiation to construct a function $x \mapsto V_x$ where $V_x$ is some such set (where we proved there exists at least one such) s.t. $x \in V_x \subseteq U$ and it is open.

As I am writing this, I feel like there is a way to eliminate choice from the proof. Here's my attempt. Suppose $U$ is a neighborhood of all its points. Denote the topology (i.e. the set of open sets) by $T$. Let $W = \{V \in T \mid V \subseteq U\}$. Let $A = \cup W$. Then as a union of open sets, $A$ is open. Claim: $A = U$. Well clearly $A \subseteq U$. Let $x \in U$. Then by assumption there exists an open set $B$ s.t. $x\in B \subseteq U$. Then $B \in W$ so $B \subseteq A$. Hence $x \in A$. Thus $U \subseteq A$ and hence $U = A$.

Am I correct that the usual proof implicitly uses choice but my proof doesn't? In my classes, every so often someone will make a big deal that a certain theorem relies on choice (e.g. Tychonoff or Hahn-Banach) yet it seems that people are throwing around choice all the time implicitly.

Comment: I think that you are right.

Comment: I think, you are  absolutely correct. An equivalent statement to AC is that every cartesian product of non-empty sets is a non-empty set. If for all $x \in U$, we denote by $S_x$ the set of all open neighbourhoods of $x$ contained in $U$, then what we really do in your first proof, is to take an element in $\prod_{x \in U} S_x$ which we can quarantee to be non-empty only by AC.

Comment: Your second proof is also correct an doesn't need AC.

Comment: I guess the reason no one notes the usage of AC in this proof is that it's not really necessary, just makes it easy for when people are first getting introduced to topology/sets.

Comment: While you're asking specifically about metric space, the idea is similar.

Comment: Also, if one wants to do topology, one should not worry too much about using the axiom of choice.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yeah, of course. I just got a little bothered when the first time my prof mentioned choice was in the proof of Tychonoff, when it was used to prove these nearly trivial facts already.

Comment: I also agree with you that AC is used all the time implicitely and nobody cares about it. I mean, what is more natural than asking a cartesian product of non-empty sets to be non-empty. Nobody would talk about AC here. Here are two more examples of the usage of DC (AC for countable sets) where nobody ever cares about it: 1) Characterization of Noetherian rings, 2) Every infinite set contains a countable set.